# View video in Landscape mode

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, landscape

I have a video in my application, but it's in portrait. I want to display it in landscape mode, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

I used this code to make my video:

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BAZO" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    //Uncomment om beeld formaat aan te passen
    //moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (IBAction)playSecondMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"00 01. Welcome" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    //Uncomment om beeld formaat aan te passen
    //moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}

-(void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BAZO" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    //Uncomment om beeld formaat aan te passen
    //moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [moviePlayerController play];

    /*-(void)loadVideo:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)type{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"BAZO"  ofType:@"m4V"]]
    if (!mp) mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [mp play];
    }*/
}
```

Maybe somebody can give me a hint or a method so I can put this to landscape?

I used this code:

```
[MPMoviePlayerController setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

but it gives me the warning :

> `MPMoviePlayerController` may not respond to `-setOrientation:animated:`

What's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem as well,
I was running it in the appDelegate file, which meant I had to force the window to change to landscape so if the original is like this:

```
-(void)playMovie {
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     pathForResource:@"intro" 
                     ofType:@"m4v"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [window addSubview:player.view];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:player.view];
    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    [player play];
}
```

all that is needed is to add these lines:

```
[window setBounds:CGRectMake(  0, 0, 480, 320)];
[window setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240];    
[window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/ 2)];
```

before the `[player play]`, and at the movie finish call, add

```
struct CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
rect.origin.x = rect.origin.y = 0.0f;   
window =[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

to reset the view.

Not sure if it's the right way to do it, but it was the only thing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`. It will handle orientation, control style, etc. I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911172/3346048) for the same.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerView = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];
```

and in the `AppDelegate.m`, declare the following function which will restrict the orientation to portrait in all cases and will only change when a video is playing

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"orientation should change");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```