# Rotate MPMoviePlayerViewController while app is in Portrait mode

Tags: ios, video, rotation

how can I autorotate MPMoviePlayerViewController according to the current mode, while the whole app is set to only portrait mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone MPMoviePlayer in Landscape Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004568/iphone-mpmovieplayer-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your base SDK is iOS 6, you can't. The whole app (in the target summary pane = the info.plist) must be set to include *all* orientations that *any* part of your app will *ever* be willing to accept. You then filter out unwanted orientations from any parts of the app that should *not* be allowed to rotate to all of those orientations, e.g. with `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that MPMoviePlayerViewController just isn't a very good class; it's inflexible. If you really want control over these things, use MPMoviePlayerController and do what you want with its view.