# MediaPlayer MPMoviePlayerController - Not playing video in Landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

Really hoping someone can help, I can get my videos to play by clicking on the button, but they always play in portrait mode, I really want them to play in full screen landscape.

Here is the code I am using here, I added a some code from here that someone said fixed it in their case, but have doubtless messed the syntax up is some way.

Please someone put me out of my misery & tell me what obvious thing I have done wrong.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@implementation SecondViewController


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]];
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
//return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
return YES;
}

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Allerjen Exclusive" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]   initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

UIView * playerView = [moviePlayerController view];
[playerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180.0f);
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);

[playerView setTransform: landscapeTransform];

moviePlayerController.fullscreen = TRUE;
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

[moviePlayerController play];


}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[moviePlayerController release];
}


@end
```

Comment: Please help :( I really can't work this out

Comment: Am facing the same problem. Have tried all the posts out there. None have helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the frame of the moviePlayer view when orientation changed,
Use following function:

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
/* Size movie view to fit parent view. */
CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset ([self.view bounds],20,20);
[[[self moviePlayerController] view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. It will handle orientation, control style etc. I referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911172/3346048 for the same.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerView = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];
```

and in the AppDelegate.m declare the following function. Which will restrict the orientation to portrait in all cases and will only change when a video is playing

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"orientation should change");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

}

Comment: Please tell reason for down voting my answer